# How to ignore saving few fields in ElasticSearch for spring-data-elasticsearch 4.x, Elastic 7.6

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.1.RELEASE and elasticsearch version 7.6.2 and trying to ignore few fields while saving to elastic. @JsonIgnore doesn't work now is there any other way to acheive this ?
I have tried, `@Field(index = false)` but this also doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `@Transient` from the `org.springframework.data.annotation` package.

Comment: p-j-meisch thanks for helping me out... this solved my problem